# How to style the text of a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, three20, ttstyledtextlabel

How to style the text of a UITableViewCell using Three20 TTStyledTextLabel ?
I tried :

```
TTStyledTextLabel* label = [[[TTStyledTextLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)] autorelease];

NSInteger i = ...;
NSString *s =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ <font color='red'>(%d)</font>", [dic objectForKey:@"name"], i];

label.text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:s lineBreaks:NO URLs:NO];

[cell.textLabel addSubview:label];
```

but the cell just keeps blank. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a frame for that  label. Otherwise it's CGRectZero.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: I made it (the code above is modified) but that still doesn't work. The cell is blank.

Comment: shouldn't you have <html> <body></body></html> tags too?

Comment: check out this guy's answer: http://forums.three20.info/discussion/172/-ttstyledtextlabel-inside-uitableviewcell/p1